# Parsing Blazor Uri Paths

Tags: blazor, webassembly

Presently we are using the site Url's to get information regarding there tenant id and location.

for example:

my-awesome-website.com/**tenant**/**centralOffice**/MyPageName/{MyPageResource}

I tried this but no joy:
[Route("{tenantId}/{subTenantId}/")]
[Route("{tenantId}/{subTenantId}/MyPageName/{MyPageResource}")]

How do we do this in Blazor WebAssembly

Answer (score 0):

In Blazor the routes are defined by the
@page directive in a component

@page “/{tenantId}/{subTenantId}/MyPageName/{MyPageResource}”

You obtain the parameters in code, eg

[Parameter] public string tenantId { get; set; }